# How to contribute to a subtree remote which is based on a tag

Tags: git, tags, subtree

I want to have a project which contains a different project as a git subtree.
This subtree is referenced to a recent release version. Releases in subtree project are done by tags.

Now, I am trying to figure out a way to contribute to subtree remote.

I know that we can contribute to subtree remote repository from within project that contains this subtree.
It seems that it works only when we are basing on branches, not for tags.

Scenario that is not working for me:

```
git subtree add --prefix libs/my_lib my_lib RELEASE_TAG --squash
vi libs/my_libs/file.txt
git add .
git commit -m"Change"
git subtree push --prefix libs/my_lib my_lib new_branch
```

Output:

```
git push using:  my_lib new_branch
fatal: 42bb2d35f859596b7ee5ae37134fa3209ffbb2f1 is not a valid 'commit' object
Can't copy commit e0364bf8b064ea60f70f9b197da4605dba28a252
```

I know that I can do it in that way, although it is not using tag:

```
git subtree add --prefix libs/my_lib my_lib master --squash
vi libs/my_libs/file.txt
git add .
git commit -m"Change"
git subtree push --prefix libs/my_lib my_lib new_branch
git push
```

How adding of subtree basing on tag differs from adding a subtree basing on a branch? And if it actually differs, then what is the proper way to push to a subtree remote which is based on a tag?

EDIT:
System: Fedora 22
Git version: 2.4.11

Answer (score 0):

I have tried on my win7, and it is working with following steps:

```
git remote add to_other <url_to_other>
git fetch to_other

git subtree add --squash --prefix my_libs/other to_other REL_TEST

# do a change
date > my_libs/other/test_file.txt
git add my_libs/other
git commit -m "new file" my_libs/other

# do push
git subtree --squash push --prefix my_libs/other to_other my_branch
```

This will create a new branch "my_branch" in to_other.

Maybe a problem with git versions?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.12.0.windows.1
```

Comment: Hello,
In fact, it seems that there may be a problem that relates to a specific Git versions. I have tried with git 2.10 on Windows, and it worked, but on 2.14 (also on windows) it did not.